# Fuzzy font in gnome shell top panel

Tags: gnome, fonts

I have Ubuntu 11.10 running gnome-shell. The font on the top panel is fuzzy as shown below.

[image: screenshot]

The font displayed in applications is clear. How to have clear font in the top panel?

Comment: Maybe check `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` if there is some shadow?

Comment: Please try if disabling the user-theme-extension helps.

Comment: @severin: I do not have user-theme-extension installed.

Answer (score 2):

Install the Cantarell font. Without it, it gets routed to Deja Vu Sans, which doesn't look as good.